# How do I run a program installed with pip in windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, pip

I installed a program with pip (e.g. simple-plotter) in windows using the following command:

```
py -m pip install simple-plotter
```

How do I run the program I installed? In Linux, I can just type the command in a terminal, but if I type in windows, I get a "not recognized as an internal or external command" or if I run in Python I get a "No module named" error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the error occurs because the Scripts folder is not on PATH in the environment variables, while in Linux it probably is (I don't know a lot of Linux so I don't know how environment variables work there, anyway):

the best way to solve this is by adding the Scripts python folder to PATH:
In my case it is `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts`

So, press WIN(windows key) + PAUSE_BREAK(near print screen key)
[image: something like this should open]

Then click on `Advanced System Configuration` (Sorry if it's not accurate, my system is in portuguese)

[image]

After that click in Environment Variables

[image: click on path and then edit]

Then, select `Path` and click `edit`

[image]

Click in new, add the path and hit the OKs

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you've installed a package via the Windows Store version of Python, try using:

```
pip show <package>
```

(Where `<package>` is the package you installed).

Then it should include the following:

```
Location: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python<some_text>\LocalCache\local-packages\Python<version>\site-packages
```

**Make sure to change the end of the path (`\site-packages`) to `\Scripts`**

Once you have this path, follow the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61494919/7589775).

TIP: A quick shortcut to get to your environment variables is to search up "environment":

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to https://pypi.org/project/simple-plotter/0.2.2/

```
python -m simple_plotter.gui
```

So maybe on windows

```
py -m simple_plotter.gui
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, and it doesn’t work saying “no module names simple_planner.gui”

Comment: this was a nice answer, worked perfectly, thanks.
$python3.11.exe -m "whatever app"